# Get certain key from a Map out of a List use scala

Tags: scala

For example:

```
data = ConcurrentHashMap(
    "allen"->{"name"->"allen","score"->"1"},
    "bill"->{"name"->"bill","score"->"2"},
    "tim"->{"name"->"tim","score"->"5"})
```

I want to get a result like `result = List("1","2","5")`
How can I manage that with scala transformation like flatten flatmap?

Comment: Provide the input in proper format or atleast specify the type of the input

Comment: @ChaitanyaWaikar done

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you have a input in the format

```
val data: Map[String, Map[String, String]] = Map(
  "allen"-> Map("name"->"allen","score"->"1"),
  "bill"->Map("name"->"bill","score"->"2"),
  "tim"->Map("name"->"tim","score"->"5"))
```

Now to fetch the result you can perform the following operation on your input

```
data.collect{
  case (k,v) => v.collect{
    case (k1,v1) if v1.map(Character.isDigit(_)).reduce(_&&_) => v1.toInt
  }
}.flatten
```

You will get the output in the format

```
res0: scala.collection.immutable.Iterable[Int] = List(1, 2, 5)
```

Also if you want the values corresponding to the scores of the players you could use

```
data.collect{
  case (k,v) => v.collect{
    case (k1,v1) if k1.equalsIgnoreCase("score") => v1.toInt
  }
}.flatten
```

In that case you will get the output as

```
res0: scala.collection.immutable.Iterable[Int] = List(1, 2, 5)
```

Please let me know if that answers your question.

Comment: The question is not very well formed, but I would assume that he is interested in the values corresponding to `score`. In that case `data.values.map(_("score"))` would be much more straightforward.

Comment: But in real situation, `score` is a attribute of a object, I cannont just simply equals it

Comment: @AIJoes you have to clarify that in the question

Answer (score 0):

I solved my own problem by this:
`val result = data.map(_._2.score)`